Decorate instance methods with decorator class that replaces method with class instance
I would like to be able to decorate instance methods with a class Step such that the methods are replaced by a Step object. At the same time, I'd like to have the option be able to instantiate a step with Step(func, options).
Working example
The example below seems to be doing just that but I'm not sure if this a cleaner way of achieving this functionality?
from typing import Callable
import functools


def step(options: "StepOptions" = None):
    """Step decorator"""
    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Step:
        return Step(func, options)
    return decorator


class Step:
    def __init__(self, func: Callable, options: "StepOptions" = None):
        self.func = func
        self.options = options if options else StepOptions()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        # Creating a bound method by passing the instance to functools.partial
        bound_method = functools.partial(self.func, instance)
        functools.update_wrapper(bound_method, self.func)

        # Return a new Step instance with the bound method
        return Step(bound_method, self.options)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Step(func: {self.func.__name__}, options: {self.options})"

class StepOptions:

    def __init__(self, retries: int = 0, timeout_s : float = None):
        self.retries = retries
        self.timeout_s = timeout_s

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"StepOptions(retries: {self.retries}, timeout_s: {self.timeout_s})"


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.steps= [
            Step(self.test_1, options=StepOptions(retries=3)),
            self.test_2,
            self.test_3,
        ]

        self.value = 2

    def test_1(self):
        print("This is test_1")
        return self.value

    @step()
    def test_2(self) -> str:
        print("This is test_2")
        return 20

    @step(StepOptions(timeout_s=10))
    def test_3(self) -> int:
        print("This is test_3")
        return 30


test = Test()

for test_step in test.steps:
    print(f"type: {type(test_step)}")
    print(test_step)
    result = test_step()
    print(result)

which outputs
type: <class '__main__.Step'>
Step(func: test_1, options: StepOptions(retries: 3, timeout_s: None))
This is test_1
2
type: <class '__main__.Step'>
Step(func: test_2, options: StepOptions(retries: 0, timeout_s: None))
This is test_2
20
type: <class '__main__.Step'>
Step(func: test_3, options: StepOptions(retries: 0, timeout_s: 10))
This is test_3
30

Alternative
In particular I'm not sure about the __get__ method of Step. So far I've only seen examples along the lines of
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, instance)

However, when doing that, print(test_2) results in
functools.partial(<bound method Step.__call__ of Step(func: test_2, options: StepOptions(retries: 0, timeout_s: None))>, <__main__.Test object at 0x78f0e1a19fc0>)

instead of
Step(func: test_2, options: StepOptions(retries: 0, timeout_s: None))

Background
A bit of background: I'm planning on using this construct in a test executor. The idea is that by creating a Step instance from each test step function, I have a place to store metadata (such as StepOptions) for each step and access that metadata in the test executor. If anyone sees a better way of doing this I'm more than happy to receive inputs!

If you have code that is working but would like reviewed for improvements, then you should post this on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Before posting on Code Review please read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users and How do I ask a good question? first.

@Booboo: I'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong community. To me it wasn't super clear that this belongs on codereview because I had an actual question ("How to decorate instance methods with decorator class that replaces method with class instance") but probably failed to convey so in my post. I'm happy to have this post moved to codereview if this is where it belongs to.

This code is nice as it is.
But, if want to simplify __get__ and not recreate "bound Step instances" you could just return partial(self.__call__, instance) in  __get__ and assume, in __call__, that the first element of args is always the instance. (You can even name it explictly, instead).
     ...
     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
         return functools.partial(self.__call__, instance)

    def __call__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        ... 

I think a codebase where you don't have to deal with several clones of each Step instance, and "bound" and "unbound" steps, can be easier to manage - although the way you did it gives you some extra flexibility.
(*) I didn't check if my suggestion will work with all the ways you want to use Step - it may require some adaptation for the "inside instance method" way.
Aside that, you may not need the def step  wrapper-  __init__ can hold its own - just check if it gets a func argument - otherwise, return immediately with return partial type(self, options=options)
